# What is the definition of a Euclidean density?

Tags: differential-geometry, distribution-theory, density-function

In page 19 of the article "Equivariant cohomology with generalized coefficients" the authors say:

> Let $V $ be an n-dimensional real vector space, let $v'$ be a non-zero element in  $ \wedge^n V^*$.  We denote by $|v'| ^{-1}\delta_V$  the element of $C^{-\infty}(V)$ defined by
> $$\int_V |v'| ^{-1} \delta_V(X) \phi(X)dX = \phi(0)$$
> for any test function $\phi$ on $V$, where $dX$ is the euclidean density on $V$ determined by $v'$.

My question is what is the definition of the Euclidean density $dX$ (determined by $v'$)?